# Background image shaping

Tags: css, css-shapes

I am trying to make website with non-rectangular backgrounds. Here is image how it should look like: https://scontent-frt3-1.xx.fbcdn.net/v/t34.0-12/13046124_10208507344992928_1508021114_n.jpg?oh=4da1595b35d18dd641146a5ff5f39ff9&oe=57206A50

I have tried so many advices from web, but nothing worked for me. 
Could anyone help me with that please?
Thanks!

Comment: what is the problem...where is the screenshot of problem you are facing??

Comment: This question is either too broad, opinion based or requires discussion and so is off-topic for Stack Overflow. If you have a specific, answerable, programming issue, please provide full details.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use `transform:skewY` to create such a design. A quick demo can be seen below, where the `background` property has been used along with some clever use of `background-position` to position "two halves" of the image together:

```css
div{
  width:100%;
  height:300px;
  position:relative;
  margin-top:50px;
  }
.part1:before,.part1:after{
    content:"";
  position:absolute;
  background:url("http://www.godhungry.org/wp-content/uploads/2015/08/6794440-free-street-wallpaper.jpg");
  background-size:200% 100%;
  background-position:0 0;
  height:100%;
  width:50%;top:0;left:0;
  transform:skewY(5deg);
  transform-origin:top left;
  }
.part1:after{
  left:50%;
  transform:skewY(-5deg);
  transform-origin:top right;
  background-position:-100% 0;
  }
.part2{
  background:url("http://www.godhungry.org/wp-content/uploads/2015/08/6794440-free-street-wallpaper.jpg");
  background-size:100% 100%;
  transform: perspective(2000px) rotateY(-30deg);
transform-origin:top right;
  }
```

```html
<div class="part1"></div>

<div class="part2"></div>
```

Comment: nice! so I have to just edit background position to set that two halves of image together? without white line...
but there is a problem - I've already found `skew`, but in first and last image, I need to set top of the image without that transformation. And I have to connect skew transform. with the second one, as you have two images there, they must be connected. You can see it on my included image. And I have no idea how to fix that
Thanks!

Comment: @HSturma You may be able to use a `perspective transform`, but would require some fiddling to make it the full screen width. Good luck!